# Why is libclang 3.7/8 not able to infer the correct type of an argument (map<string, int>)?

Tags: python, llvm-clang, libclang

I am using the Python API for libclang. I have a little test program that prints the AST (node types, names, types) of a parsed file:

```
from clang import cindex


def print_ast(node, depth):
    line = "  " * depth + "Node: %s" % node.kind
    if node.spelling:
        line += ", '%s'" % node.spelling
    if node.type.spelling:
        line += " (type: '%s')" % node.type.spelling
    print(line)
    for child in node.get_children():
        print_ast(child, depth + 1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    lib_path = "/usr/lib/llvm-3.8/lib/"
    cindex.Config.set_library_path(lib_path)
    #cindex.Config.set_library_file(lib_path + "libclang-3.8.so")
    index = cindex.Index.create()
    options = (cindex.TranslationUnit.PARSE_INCOMPLETE |
            cindex.TranslationUnit.PARSE_SKIP_FUNCTION_BODIES)
    filename = "map.hpp"
    with open(filename, "r") as infile:
        content = infile.read()
    translation_unit = index.parse(
        filename, unsaved_files=[(filename, content)], options=options)
    cursor = translation_unit.cursor
    print_ast(cursor, 0)
```

The file "map.hpp" contains the following code:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>


int lookup(std::map<std::string, int>& m)
{
    return m["test"];
}
```

I get the following output with libclang-3.5 (and 3.6, installed with sudo pip install libclang-3.5-dev python-clang-3.5 on Ubuntu 14.04 / 16.04):

```
...
Node: CursorKind.FUNCTION_DECL, 'lookup' (type: 'int std::map<std::string, int> &)')
  Node: CursorKind.PARM_DECL, 'm' (type: 'std::map<std::string, int> &')
    Node: CursorKind.NAMESPACE_REF, 'std'
    Node: CursorKind.TEMPLATE_REF, 'map'
    Node: CursorKind.NAMESPACE_REF, 'std'
    Node: CursorKind.TYPE_REF, 'string' (type: 'string')
```

... and with libclang-3.8 (and 3.7):

```
  Node: CursorKind.FUNCTION_DECL, 'lookup' (type: 'int (int &)')
    Node: CursorKind.PARM_DECL, 'm' (type: 'int &')
```

So it seems to be possible to determine the correct type of 'm' but either the API has changed in libclang 3.7 or it is broken or something else is wrong. The parser does not seem to have any problem with strings or with maps but when I include both headers I get this problem.

Comment: Looks like you're just missing the compiler flags to add the system include paths (in some cases). The hint that this is happening is that std::map is being resolved to int (the default type). Best practice to avoid these hassles with libclang is to always check the diagnostics member of the translation unit

Comment: Yes! Thank you. I checked the diagnostics and got '<Diagnostic severity 4, location <SourceLocation file '/usr/include/wchar.h', line 39, column 11>, spelling "'stdarg.h' file not found">'. After adding the include path "-I/usr/lib/clang/3.8.0/include/" it works. I wonder why this was not a problem before 3.7?